# Background drawable does not work

Tags: android

I've created this drawable resource, `backgroundactivity`, to use as my app's background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <item
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <shape
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#BFEFFF"
                android:centerColor="#B0E2FF"
                android:endColor="#82CFFD"
                android:type="linear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I want to set this background on all my activity, so I've tried to put this drawable resource in the `styles.xml` like this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/backgroundactivity</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="@android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But in this way it didn't work: the background still stay white as default. I've also tried to replace `android:background` with `android:windowBackground`, but it causes my application to be completely black.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your backgroundactivity.xml is done correctly, remove .xml extension.

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/backgroundactivity.xml</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/backgroundactivity</item>
```

Comment: oh, sorry, it was only a typo that I made when writing that line in the question: in my application there is no `.xml` so it isn't that problem

Comment: try atribute windowBackground instead of background however it's from api 21. in v21 styles

Comment: with this attribute my application is completely black. not just the background, even the `View`s are not shown